# ObjectDataSource and CacheKeyDependency possible bug

Tags: .net, caching, objectdatasource

I have noticed a quite strange behavior with an `ObjectDataSource` using **CacheKeyDependency**

When I set the `CacheKeyDependency` in the declarative .aspx syntax, the `ObjectDataSource.Selecting` event (and Selected) gets called **twice**!!! 
(and of course also the related Database `SelectMethod` gets called twice)

But, if I remove the `CacheKeyDependency` the `ObjectDataSource` Selecting Event occurs, correctly, only once!

Speed concerning apart, this could potentially break my code-behind logic if I assume that Selecting/Selected gets called only once...

Have any of you noticed that?

This behavior could be ascribed to a bug in ASP.NET or maybe there some bug in my code?

*PS: The timeline of the events are like so, with in bold the duplicated ones:*

```
PageLoad

ODS_Selecting

DataLayer Select

ODS_Selected

ODS_Filtering

GridView_DataBound

**ODS_Selecting**

**DataLayer Select**

**ODS_Selected**

ODS_Filtering

GridView_DataBound

GridView_PreRender
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Cache` value for the `CacheKeyDependency` must be set. If not, the `ObjectDataSource` cache is essentially disabled, which can result in the select method being called twice.

See the example in the [Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.cachekeydependency%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Cache[ObjectDataSource2.CacheKeyDependency] = "CacheExample";
    }
}
```

Found the following approach to work the best. The MS example expires the cache when the page load is not a post back.

```
if (null == Cache[ObjectDataSource2.CacheKeyDependency])
{
    Cache[ObjectDataSource2.CacheKeyDependency] = new Object();
}
```